# Arrange list of <span>s in rows and columns using CSS and/or JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Input:** a list of an unknown number of span elements, contained within a parent span. e.g.

```
<span id="parent">
<span id="child-1">1</span>
<span id="child-2">2</span>
<span id="child-3">3</span>
<span id="child-4">4</span>
<span id="child-5">5</span>
<span id="child-6">6</span>
<span id="child-7">7</span>
<span id="child-8">8</span>
<span id="child-9">9</span>
<span id="child-10">10</span>
...
...
...
</span>
```

**Output:** using CSS classes and/or JavaScript/jQuery, without adding `<span>`s inside the parent span (in order to divide the child-spans into groups) - I would like to cause the child-spans to be rendered - both **vertically and horizontally** - in N rows and M columns. N and M should change often so I cannot use a solution that will add html elements into the parent-span in order to divide the child-spans into groups.

For example, if I have 12 child-spans and N(rows)=4 and M(columns)=3, then in the browser I should see:

Horizontal order:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Vertical order:

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

Thanks!

Comment: @James Montagne: +1 for the link - only half read it and was in stitches at times!

Comment: sounds like another pinterest-like layout

Comment: @James Montagne - First you learn the rules, then you can break them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set the float style of your inner spans to "left" in a static style block. You also have to give them a constant width to let them fit in columns.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #parent span { float: left; display: block; width: 100px; }
</style>
```

Then you can rearrange your spans in JavaScript by reappending them to the parent element in the proper order and dynamically changing the clear style to separate rows. This is my sample code:

```
function makeHorizontalOrder(rows, cols)
{
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            var index = 1 + col + row * cols;
            var span = document.getElementById("child-" + index);
            if (span)
            {
                span.style.clear = col ? "none" : "left";
                parent.appendChild(span);
            }
        }
    }
}

function makeVerticalOrder(rows, cols)
{
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            var index = 1 + row + col * rows;
            var span = document.getElementById("child-" + index);
            if (span)
            {
                span.style.clear = col ? "none" : "left";
                parent.appendChild(span);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the two functions only differ in the index calculation.

Comment: I figured out what was my problem. Some other CSS disabled yours. I removed it and now it works! Thank you for the `style.clear` trick.

Answer (score 1):

The columns are done in pure CSS, the order can be done in javascript.

Give each span a fixed width, then set the parent span to a fixed width that keeps the other spans in the required number of "columns".

```
<style type="text/css">
#parent {
  display: block;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red
}

#parent span {
  width: 1.3em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>

<span id="parent">
  <span id="0">0</span>
  <span id="1">1</span>
  <span id="2">2</span>
  <span id="3">3</span>
  <span id="4">4</span>
  <span id="5">5</span>
  <span id="6">6</span>
  <span id="7">7</span>
  <span id="8">8</span>
  <span id="9">9</span>
  <span id="10">10</span>
  <span id="11">11</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

well this one is the easiest solution for horizontal

```
$('#parent').css('text-align','left').children().each(function(i){if((i+1)%3==0) $(this).after('<br>')})
```

yet to a solution other than the one ft1 gave for vertical.....